# In .Net, what is the fastest way to recursively find all files from a root directory?

Tags: .net, search, filesystems

I want to search a directory for all files that match a certain pattern.
Surprisingly, I have not had to do this since vb6 (Dir)... I'm sure things have changed since then!

-Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use **SearchOption.AllDirectories** parameter:

```
using System.IO;

Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: yes, things have changed since Dir in VB6, the System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories means you don't need to recurse the directories yourself anymore.

Comment: @Hamish But you might still want to manually recurse directories to avoid/handle UnauthorizedAccessExceptions.